# Component Not Updating In Sync

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-dom

I have a component which renders a pie chart pertaining to each user, with values unique to each user. When I click on a particular user's name, it should re-render the pie chart with the values for that specified user. Instead, it is delayed on the first click, and does not update until I click onto another user. For example (using the link provided), if I click on user 'Bob Dickinson' the pie chart does not render until I click again on the next user 'Eugine Smith' which then renders the data pertaining to Bob Dickinson but under Eugine Smith's name, and the component subsequently lags behind on each render. I've listed my code below and a link to the live example:

Link:  https://2b0057e3.ngrok.io/dashboard

StudentGraph component:

```
import React from 'react';
import { Link } from 'react-router';
import { FormattedMessage } from 'react-intl';
import chart from 'chart.js';

export default class StudentGraph extends React.PureComponent { // eslint-disable-line react/prefer-stateless-function
     constructor(props) {
      super(props);
      this.plot = this.plot.bind(this);
  }
  plot(){
   var ctx = document.getElementById("graph2");
var data = {
    labels: [
        "Budget Used",
        "Budget Remaining"
    ],
    datasets: [
        {
            data: [this.props.budgetUsed,this.props.budgetRemain ],
            backgroundColor: [
                "#FF6384",
                "#90ee90"
            ],
            hoverBackgroundColor: [
                "#36A2EB",
                "#36A2EB"
            ]
        }]
}; 
var myChart = new Chart(ctx, {
    type: 'pie',
    data: data
});
 }

 componentWillUpdate(){
     this.plot()
 }



  render() {
    return (
        <div>
        <h3>Budget Started: 10,250.00</h3>
        <h3>Budget Used: {this.props.budgetUsed}</h3>
        <h3>Budget Remaining: {this.props.budgetRemain}</h3>
          <div style = {{ width: '20%'}}>
            <canvas id="graph2" width="100" height="100"></canvas>
          </div>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

As a workaround you should call `plot` function also in one of the [`componentWillReceiveProps`](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/react-component.html#componentwillreceiveprops) or [`componentWillUpdate`](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/react-component.html#componentwillupdate) lifecycle functions. remember to check if `budgetUsed` and `budgetRemain` are changed if you are using `componentWillReceiveProps`.
Add these methods to your class and they are automatically invoked by React.

Here, you are trying to map an imperative library (chart.js) to React's functional nature, and generally it is better to use React specific components if you can (There are definitely some good React charting components out there).

Comment: I figured out the issue. The props was updating, but I was using the old props value based off of the componentWill life-cycle methods. Instead I switched it to componentDidUpdate and it grabs the new props, instead of going off the previous generated values.

Answer (score 0):

I figured out the issue. The props was updating, but I was using the old props value based off of the componentWill life-cycle methods. Instead I switched it to componentDidUpdate and it grabs the new props, instead of going off the previous generated values.

```
import React from 'react';
import { Link } from 'react-router';
import { FormattedMessage } from 'react-intl';
import chart from 'chart.js';

export default class StudentGraph extends React.PureComponent { // eslint-disable-line react/prefer-stateless-function
     constructor(props) {
      super(props);
      this.plot = this.plot.bind(this);
  }
  plot(){
   var ctx = document.getElementById("graph2");
var data = {
    labels: [
        "Budget Used",
        "Budget Remaining"
    ],
    datasets: [
        {
            data: [this.props.budgetUsed,this.props.budgetRemain ],
            backgroundColor: [
                "#FF6384",
                "#90ee90"
            ],
            hoverBackgroundColor: [
                "#36A2EB",
                "#36A2EB"
            ]
        }]
}; 
var myChart = new Chart(ctx, {
    type: 'pie',
    data: data
});
 }

 componentDidUpdate(){
     this.plot();
 }


  render() {
    return (
        <div>
        <h3>Budget Started: 10,250.00</h3>
        <h3>Budget Used: {this.props.budgetUsed}</h3>
        <h3>Budget Remaining: {this.props.budgetRemain}</h3>
          <div style = {{ width: '20%'}}>
            <canvas id="graph2" width="100" height="100"></canvas>
          </div>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```